# Как сделать выбор из ранее выбранного Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite3

У меня задача найти подходящую анкету из базы данных, данный алгоритм поиска должен происходить в несколько этапов, при этом на каждом из таковых часть анкет должна отсеиваться, а часть оставаться. Я думал, что в Sqlite3 есть такой оператор как UNSELECT, но такого не нашел, поэтому вопрос в том, как такое можно реализовать и вообще как работать с уже выбранными элементами БД.

Comment: Чем обычный `WHERE ... AND ...` не устроил?

Comment: тем, что алгоритм поиска происходит в несколько этапов, то есть это не один запрос к бд

Comment: Что мешает во втором этапе повторить запрос из первого этапа, но просто приписать к нему этот самый AND?

Comment: ну технически ничего не мешает, но все таки я верю в то, что есть какая-то возможность работы с выделением, поэтому и спрашиваю тут

Comment: В sql не существует такого понятия «выделение», каждый запрос работает независимо от других